# read specific line from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After getting a DOM, everything is fine to innerHTML, but I dont want the full text to be put in the div.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var extractedtext;
        extractedtext=xmlhttp.responseText;
        ;
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=extractedtext;



        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","list2.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setInterval (loadXMLDoc, 1000);
}
```

how to get a range of specific lines at extractedtext considering it is a huge txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count loop with `indexOf('\n')` until you've done it the number of times as lines you want

```
function getLines(haystack, from, toIncluding) {
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    haystack = '\n' + haystack; // makes life easier
    --from;                     // start from "line 1"
    while (from-->0 && i !== -1)
        --toIncluding, i = haystack.indexOf('\n', i + 1);
    if (i === -1) return '';
    j = i;
    while (toIncluding-->0 && j !== -1)
        j = haystack.indexOf('\n', j + 1);
    if (j === -1) j = haystack.length;
    return haystack.slice(i + 1, j);
}

var str = '1\n2\n3\n4';
getLines(str, 2, 3); // "2\n3"
getLines(str, 1, 1); // "1"
getLines(str, 4, 4); // "4"
getLines(str, 1, 4); // "1\n2\n3\n4"
```

Comment: `indexOf()` has to perform an `O(n)` scan through the string. You can do the whole operation in 1 pass (see my answer).

Comment: @MattBall `indexOf` will only start it's scan from the index passed as the second parameter (see [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.7)), so it will "pick up where it left off". My `j = i;` line also means that it doesn't start from the beginning to find the end, either.

Comment: @MattBall _JavaScript_ loops tend to be much slower than the internal ones (which would be in _C_ or something and optimised by compiler) + _Array_ can be quite slow, `join` will be calling `toString` on each item too, remember = visible performance difference when you don't use them